# how do i assign value of php variable to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript

```
<html>
<head>
 <?php

         $bldg_number=-1;
 ?>
                      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                      var bldg=<?php echo $bldg_number; ?>
                      if( bldg < 0)
                          {
                            alert("me");
                          }
                      else
                          {
                            alert("hi");
                          }
                    </script>
```

**i was expecting the output a alert with message me but there is no output when i am running this page please tell me why the value of php variable is not passing to javscript variable**

Comment: Provided this page *is* being run via the PHP interpreter, that all looks fine other than the minor niggle that you should have a semicolon at the end of your `var` statement (the JavaScript interpreter will insert one for you automatically). So you'll have to quote more of the page and/or describe more of the context, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: No output whatsoever indicates there's likely a syntax error; check the source code that's generated by the PHP code, and see what that script actually ends up looking like.

Comment: @Thief: Well, *now* @Jaspreet definitely has an answer he can accept. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs a semicolon at the end of the `var` line (keep reading for why):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                      //               here --------------v
                      var bldg=<?php echo $bldg_number; ?>;
                      if( bldg < 0)
                          {
                            alert("me");
                          }
                      else
                          {
                            alert("hi");
                          }
                    </script>
```

JavaScript has a feature called "[Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9)" that would normally make that error harmless (whether the *feature* is harmless is another story), but unfortunately PHP messes it up because ASI only kicks in if there's a linebreak where the missing semicolon should be, and [PHP eats the linebreak following the `?>` tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> ...when PHP hits the `?>` closing tags, it simply starts outputting whatever it finds (except for an immediately following newline - see [instruction separation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) )

So what actually gets output to your page is:

```
var bldg=-1    if( bldg < 0)
```

...which is a syntax error in JavaScript. Adding the semicolon fixes it, because then the output is:

```
var bldg=-1;    if( bldg < 0)
```

...which is valid.

Comment: T.J Crowder, adding the semicolon works, without semicolon doesn't work. I think most of the browsers doesn 't support Automatic Semicolon Insertioning. Chrome works the same.

Comment: Ok, got it. Anyway, the problem with the above code was the missing breakline. I don't want to discuss about this feature that I wouldn't recommend to anyone. I've just proposed a solution to the problem arised.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Actually the missing `;` does matter, as PHP as the habit of removing the first whitespace after a closing `?>` (even newlines). So what happens here is, that the linebreak in the given code will not be there in the final rendered code. Breaking the javascript because of the missing `;`. One could add a `space` after the `?>` which would leave the newline (or just add the `;`).

Comment: @Yoshi: Ah hah! ***That's*** the crucial information missing from the answers here. (Wow is that a "feature" I would remove from PHP.)

Comment: @T.J Crowder Me too, it guarantees for long and ugly debugging sessions ;)

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain and cleaned up comments. (Just my own, I'm not a moderator.)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var bldg=<?php echo $bldg_number; ?>;
```